# Going to the letter printed on the keyboard in Listbox is there in Listview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Going to the letter pressed on the keyboard in Listbox is there in Listview?
When I press the keyboard key to access items in the list view sub-item, I want it to select the ones that match the first letter. Like a list box.

Comment: There's nothing to do that automatically, as far as I'm aware. You'd have to put some thought into the logic required and then try to implement that in code. You need to do the first part for yourself and then ask a specific question if you have an issue with the second part.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListBox` must have focus for this to work. You can set the `ActiveControl` of the `Form` or the user can tab to the control or click in the ListBox. You can also call `ListBox.Focus()` but not from the `Form` events.

The key pressed is returned by `KeyChar` and is case sensitive. The items in `ListBox.Items` are `Objects` so we need to call `.ToString` to be able to compare them with letter. `String`s are really array of `Char`. We can use the Linq `.First` method on this array to get the first `Char` in the array. Then we `.Add` or `.Remove` the item from the `SelectedItems` collection.

```
Private lst As New List(Of String) From {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Be sure you have multiple select set - this can be done at design time
    ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
    ListBox1.DataSource = lst
    'Clears the default selection of the first item
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    'The ListBox must have focus to the key press code to work
    ActiveControl = ListBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyPress
    Dim letter = e.KeyChar
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.First = letter Then
            ListBox1.SelectedItems.Add(ListBox1.Items(i))
        Else
            ListBox1.SelectedItems.Remove(ListBox1.Items(i))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

As per comment, check out the `FindItemWithText` and `FindNearestItem` methods of the ListView. There are several overloads. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=net-5.0

Comment: My impression of the question is that the OP wants functionality for a `ListView` that works like that which already exists for a `ListBox`.